# Converting DVD (movie) discs into VCD (movie) discs quickly and easily

Tags: video-conversion

I'm looking for an application which can directly convert DVD (movie) discs into VCD (movie) discs quickly and easily.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your questions on SU seem split between Ubuntu and Windows, I'll give the easy answer: [DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html) is the only program for such I ever used and it worked brilliantly.